# How can I tell rails where to look for a specific template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have an model called Purchase.rb. each purchase is created through a form as follows.

```
<%= form_for(@purchase) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Describe something you are interested in buying.", :maxlength=>"254" %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>

  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

when they are created they are displayed with a partial stored in app/views/purchases/_purchase.html.erb. To add photos, I have put

```
<%= form_for(@purchase) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

in the purchase itself. I am using paperclip. So the idea is that people can click on a field that is part of the purchase and add a photo to the view.

the error I get says

```
Missing template purchases/users#show, application/users#show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/alex/rails_projects/tradespring!/app/views"
```

I want it to look at app/views/users#show, not app/views/purchases/users#show

edit:

here is the show action of the userscontroller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @purchases= @user.purchases
    @sales= @user.sales
    @purchase=Purchase.new
    @sale=Sale.new
  end
```

and here is the routes.rb

```
Tradespring::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :pcomments
    resources :scomments
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :purchases do
    resources :pcomments
  end
  resources :sales do
    resources :scomments
  end

  get "static_pages/home"

  get "static_pages/about"

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new' 
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

finally, here is the what I want to happen when I submit the picture form. Im not 100% sure it should be under update.

```
class PurchasesController < ApplicationController
 def update
    @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:id])
    if @purchase.update_attributes(params[:purchase])
      flash[:success] = "Picture added"

      redirect_to :back
    else
      render 'users/show'
    end
  end
```

also here is the app/views/user/show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<p>
<%= mail_to(@user.email, name="email this user", :encode => "javascript") %>
</p>

<div id="purchases">

<%= form_for(@purchase) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Describe something you are interested in buying.", :maxlength=>"254" %>
    <%= f.file_field :photo %>
    <p1> Note: There is a 254 character limit. Be sure to include useful information such as product specifications, how much you are willing to pay, and shipping info (where you live, if you want to pick it up locally, ect.). Further detail is best left to email.</p1>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.purchases.any? %>
      <h3>Purchases (<%= @user.purchases.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="purchases">
        <%= render @purchases %>
      </ol>
<% end %>
</div>


<div id="sales">

<%= form_for(@sale) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "Describe something you are interested in selling.", :maxlength=>"254" %>
    <p1> Note: There is a 254 character limit. Be sure to include useful information such as product specifications, price, payment methods accepted, and shipping info (where you live, if you are willing to ship it, ect.). Further detail is best left to email. </p1>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<% if @user.sales.any? %>
      <h3>Sales (<%= @user.sales.count %>)</h3>
      <ol class="sales">
        <%= render @sales %>
      </ol>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the `PurchasesController` doing for the show action? are you trying to redirect/return a user instance? post the relevant routes as well

Comment: there is no show action in the purchases controller. There is a show action in the users controller. On the users#show page there is a list of a bunch of purchases that belong to the user. I will post the users show action and the routes though

Comment: in your PurChasesController put `render 'users/show'` to the place you want.

Comment: well I am updating the purchase, so do I need to add an update action in the purchases controller, or would it be edit? I assume this is where render 'users/show' would go

Comment: `form_for(@purchases)` means that the form submission will be handled by the purchases controller, and what will happen depends on your create/update actions

Comment: I'm also assuming the error you are referring to occurs on form submission (do clarify if that is not the case)

Comment: the error occurs on form submission of the picture, not the purchase. I have added the update action of my purchases_controller.rb file to the question

Comment: post the `app/views/users/show.html.erb` , `render 'users/show'` should be referencing that

Comment: i just did, though its a bit long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I needed to define the action of the second form for. I guess by default, the form for assumes that you want the create action. In this case I wanted it to use the update action so I needed to change it to <%= form_for((@purchase), :url => { :action => "update" }) do |f| %>